# Write formulas in specific languages of group.

Tags: group-theory, logic, arithmetic, propositional-calculus, additive-categories

So, for each of the following groups write a formula in the language of group theory, which holds in given group, but doesn't hold in others two.

**$(i)$ The integers with addition** \ I think it's $\{\Bbb{Z},+,-,0\}$

**$(ii)$ Positive reals with multiplication** \ I think it's $\{\Bbb{R}_+,*,\,^{-1},1\}$

**$(iii)$ Permutations of $\{a,b,c\}$ with composition** \ I don't know exatly what it is.

So, I found such formula for $(ii)$, it's:

**$\forall x \exists y(x=y*y)$;**

This formula holds for $(ii)$ but doesn't hold for $(i)$, 'cause $\forall x\exists y(x=y*y)$ to $(i)$ is $\forall x\exists y(x=y+y)$, doesn't hold for $x=1$.

But I've stuck on others groups and I cannot fid anything right for them.
Notice that we don't have '$>$' and '$<$' for the first two, and I'm not sure about last one.

Comment: (iii) has an element of order $2$, which you should be able to express as a mathematical formula (i.e. using first order logic). I guess you could then do (i) as the negation of (ii) and of (iii).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know anything about group theory, $(iii)$ is just $S_3$ and has exactly $6$ elements (which you can write in the language of groups since you have equality). Clearly, "Having exactly 6 elements" is true in $(iii)$ and false in $(i)$ and $(ii)$. We call this sentence $\varphi$.

As you noted, $\mathbb{R}_+ \models \forall x \exists y (x = y*y)$. This is false in $(i)$ and it is also false in $(iii)$. Notice that a transposition, i.e. $(ab)$, cannot be written as the composition of two permutations. We call this sentence $\psi$.

Finally, as Derek Holt suggested, we are already done. Notice that $\neg \varphi \wedge \neg \psi$ is a sentence in FOL which does not hold in $(ii)$ (since $\psi$ holds in $(ii)$) and does not hold in $(iii)$ (since $\varphi$ holds in $(iii)$), but does hold in $(i)$ because $\neg \psi$ and $\neg \varphi$ hold in $(i)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kyle Gannon, but I'm not sure you're right about ∀x∃y(x=y∗y) for (ii), because (Z) means all numbers, even roots, so formula holds correctly and in every time. But thank you for answering for (iii).

Comment: @DanielGrankin: $(ii)$ is $\mathbb{R}_+$. Every positive real has a (unique) positive  square root.

Comment: @DanielGrankin: I found an error in my second paragraph. Sorry! It should read that $\forall x \exists y (x = y * y)$ is false in (i) and (iii).